# deal with image content in js (jquery or html5)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Now I'm fetching image from a dynamic url:

```
<img src="http://imageserver/some/source/xxxx.jpg" />
```

And the behavior or imageserver is as below, which I can't modify here:

1. If the specific image was found, return the image content with status code 200;
2. If not found, return the particular image content (as below), also with status code 200;
   [image]

So, till now, I cannot find an efficient way to determine whether this image exists.

And I turned to think if I can read the image content data and compare (maybe hashcode?) the content to judge it.

Is there any way to do this? Using javascript, html5 or jQuery?

Hope your help, master!

Comment: They only way would be to have the bytes of the "known" image already in memory so you could compare with the given results. Using JQuery, you can register the load() method on your image.

Comment: Does the no picture image have a name? Just check for it

Comment: you should save this image in your folder and should return a flag from server exists or not,if image not exists on server then show it.to save the response time...

Comment: @Sterling Archer the **no picture** name is always the url I request, no more information on it.

Comment: @Devendra Soni Well, but the point is that the behavior of `imageserver` is not controlled by me. More, I (no, my customer) just want the functional, not the performance.

Comment: @P. Lalonde That was exact solution I wanted, but could you please point out an implementation (at least a thread) on it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had in mind, using jquery ... but still would need some workaround, since you could get async responses.

```
var noPictureImageData;

$(window).load(function () {
    // Get the original "no picture image"
    $.ajax({
        url: "url_to_no_picture.jpg",
        success: function (imagedata) {
            noPictureImageData = imagedata;
        }
    });

    // Once your image is loaded, then compare their bytes.
    $("#image").load(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("src"),
            success: function (imagedata) {
                /* Effectively compare contents, not sure about how conversion into strings performance could be. */
                if( true  ) {

                    // You have your no picture image loaded.

                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, this might work well, but not on my case. Because I got an error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://inman' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: So is there anyway to fetch the data from the `<img>` tag?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't